# Cascading Drop down Racing , MVC Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I'm working on MVC.Net project that has a page this page has two cascading dropdown lists (Dropdown A, Dropdown B) the main is Dropdown A. I implemented the cascading manually using Jquery Ajax in the Dropdown A Change Event and they work fine except this case:-

Let Say that the Dropdown A has two values (Val A, Val B) and when choosing Val B Ajax Request initiated but will do much more business logic *(take more time)* on the server side than the case of Val A.

**The problem** is when I choose Val B and do not wait for Dropdown B to be populated with the ajax result and I choose Val A Directly, the Dropdown B get populated with the Ajax result of Val A first (*take no time*) Then Val B Ajax Result(after business logic finish (*Take more time*))

**The Issue** I want to guarantee that the Ajax Result of the last Selected Value will always win *without Disabling* the Dropdown A till the Ajax Result come.

Comment: Cancel the cascade request before making another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **refactored** and **optimized** the code for the business logic that was taking a long time to *take no time* and that do the trick instead of going the hard way. as canceling the ajax request triggers the ajax error handler which is not acceptable for this case. And there weren't any helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized my logic is complete broken without understand the underlying issue — The fact that the order of return data is completely random. According to freedom cancelling existing AJAX request seems to be a promising solution but I'm not sure how to do that.

The ugly yet 100% working way for your case would be to **return data along with your request param (e.g. selected value)** so that you perform binding only if the response's request param match with your latest selected value.

```
var selectedValue;

$('#ddlA').on('change', function() {
    selectedValue = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
       method: 'GET'
       url   : ** AJAX url **,
       data  : { key: selectedValue }
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        if (** result's key ** === selectedValue) {
           // bind #ddlB
       }
    });
});
```

This might be the simplest yet naive way without cancelling client/server process.

Comment: Did not work, Say we have two values in ddlA (A, B) user chosen A and it is waiting to done, while the user has chosen B and while it waiting done A reached the done here
      
        globalCounter++;

will run and  the done of the B will not bind as (localCounter != globalCounter) which is wrong

Comment: apologize as I didn't double check my psuedocode and my mind is kinda bloggy at midnight.. How about the latest edit? The idea remains the same but I wonder if it will have race condition issue as I'm no Javascript expert.

Comment: The Same Idea Just try to apply the previous scenario in my first comment, it will still have the race condition as the change handler fired in parallel

Comment: I see, it seems I've messed up with the scope then.. I believe closure would solve the issue but I'm not familiar with it. Can you try it out and let me know whether it works with the latest edit?

Comment: A closure is a function having access to the parent scope, even after the parent function has closed. How do you think it could help here?